# Verificar consulta MySQL con Java Swing

Tags: java, mysql, login

Tengo un **login-password** para controlar acceso a mi aplicación en `Java Swing.`

Con la siguiente base de datos `MySQL`:

```
CREATE TABLE administradores (
    usuario VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO administradores (usuario, password) VALUES 
("admin", "admin");
```

¿Por qué siempre me sale "Administrador existente..." y no me da la bienvenida siendo la contraseña correcta?

**cargar_administradores():**

```
public static ArrayList cargar_administradores(String usuario, String password) {
    ArrayList<Administrador> administradores = new ArrayList<Administrador>();
    String bbdd = Conexiones.bbdd;
    Connection c = (Connection) Conexiones.conexion_a_BBDD(bbdd);
    Statement stm;
    ResultSet rs;
    try {
        stm = c.createStatement();
        String consulta_clientes = "SELECT * FROM administradores WHERE usuario = '" +usuario+ "' AND password = '" +password+ "'";
        rs = stm.executeQuery(consulta_clientes);
        //System.out.println("CONSULTA TODOS LOS ADMINISTRADORES: ");
        while (rs.next()) {
            Administrador administrador = new Administrador();
            administrador.setUsuario(rs.getString("usuario")); 
            administrador.setPassword(rs.getString("password")); 
            administradores.add(administrador);
        }
        c.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    /*for(int i=0;i<administradores.size();i++){
        System.out.println(administradores.get(i)); //funciona
    }*/ 
    return administradores;
}
```

**Interfaz:**

```
private void button_accederActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
        String usuario = textfield_usuario.getText();
        String password = textfield_password.getText();

        if(Conexiones.conexion_a_BBDD("agenda") == null){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡MySQL failed!", "ADMINISTRADOR", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            this.dispose();
        } else if (textfield_usuario.getText().trim().isEmpty()){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡Debes rellenar el usuario!", "ADMINISTRADOR", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            textfield_usuario.requestFocus();
        } else if (textfield_password.getText().trim().isEmpty()){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡Debes rellenar la contaseña!", "ADMINISTRADOR", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            textfield_password.requestFocus();
        }else if (Conexiones.cargar_usuarios().contains(textfield_usuario.getText())){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡Administrador existente pero contraseña inválida!", "ADMINISTRADOR", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            textfield_usuario.requestFocus();
        } else if(Conexiones.cargar_administradores(usuario, password).size()>0) { //parece que no llega aquí
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡Bienvenido "+usuario+"!", "ADMINISTRADOR", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            Index i = new Index();
            i.setVisible(true);
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡No existe este administrador en la base de datos!", "ADMINISTRADOR", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            textfield_usuario.requestFocus();
        }
    }
```

Comment: hola, y si pruebas a cambiar `=` por `LIKE` en la query sql?

Comment: @DaniDekk Persiste el problema.

Comment: amigo cuando entra en el `if (Conexiones.cargar_usuarios().contains(textfield_usuario.getText()))` luego ya no puede entrar a otro `else`, prueba a quitar los `else` dejando `if`

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que es porque se ejecuta el metodo cargar_usuarios() antes que el metodo cargar_administradores(), podrias cambiarlos de lugar, de todas formas, no creo que sea bueno evaluar de esa forma, podrías crear un solo metodo para validar usuarios y dependiendo del tipo de usuario (user o admin) haga tal o cual cosa.